# Warning comparision of unintentional references c#

Tags: visual-studio, warnings

at first thanks for reading.
 I'm working on a proyect on Visual Studio 2015 - C#, and i get this warning

> CS0252 Possible comparison of unintentional references; To get a comparison of values, convert the left side to type 'string'

I've checked the Microsoft website but i don't understand why the warning appear.

The line where the warning refer:

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     if (comboBox1.SelectedItem == "Por ID Cliente")
     {
            txtBoxID.Visible = true;
            lblID.Visible = true;
        lblID.Text = "ID Cliente:";
     }
}
```

I'm doing this to show a label and a textbox depending on the item selected on comboBox1.
 When i try to compile it works!, but i'd like to delete the warning

Comment: Operator == is not a virtual method.  The comparison is unlikely to be true, except in the corner-case of adding interned strings to the combobox.  Could happen, why it is warning and not an error.  Using .ToString() is very good advice, now you'll use the operator==() overload that the String class provides.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to access the object as string. You should use comboBox1.SelectedItem.Value or comboBox1.SelectedValue.

you should check:

```
if (comboBox1.Items.FindByValue("value") != null) {
    comboBox1.SelectedValue = "value";
}
```